# dynamically name an array to the `$scope` to be used in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to dynamically name an array to the `$scope` like this

```
$scope['list_'+id] = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

Now I want to use it in `ng-repeat` like this

```
<li ng-repeat="list in ['list_'+department.$id]">
```

---

**but that did not iterate over the array so i tried the following**

```
if(typeof $scope.L == 'undefined'){ $scope.L={}};

$scope.L['list_'+id] = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

html

```
<li ng-repeat="list in L['list_'+department.$id]">
```

that did work for AngularJS but it did not init well with AngularFire

---

so i want to make version1 work because I think it is close to working well with angularjs and angularfire....Can you see why method 1 is not working?? Can you see why method2 didnt work with angularfire until I modified the array in the session??

Answer (score 0):

use a function to call a dynamic var name in the ng-repeat. instead of

```
<li ng-repeat="list in ['list_'+department.$id]">
```

do

```
<li ng-repeat="list in get_list(department.$id)">
```

that function looks like this

```
$scope.get_list = function(id) {
    return $scope['list_'+id];
}
```

Comment: Using $rootScope as a data store is a terrible practice. Use a service